# freebase superclass subclass of a concept topic

Tags: freebase

is there a way to get the recursive superclass concepts of a concept from freebase? For example, i would call the topic "/games/game_publisher" a concept, and I would like to know if it has any superclasses (e.g., /organization/organization would make sense).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Freebase Types (the equivalent of your "concept") don't have an inheritance structure.  They do however have "included types".  One key difference is that an included type only gets added to a topic by when it's main type does by convention of the web client (or other client), but after that it can be removed or re-added independently.  For example, Deceased Person has Person as an included type and it's unlikely anyone would ever remove the latter, but Author also has Person as included type because that's the case for the overwhelming majority of authors, but for so-called "corporate authors" one would remove Person and add Organization.

So, the included types does carry some semantic information, but it's not as strong as a super/sub-class relationship.